# Onenote API response received with invalid grant error for a random user

Tags: outlook, access-token, onenote, onenote-api

URL to get new access token using refresh token:

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf?grant_type=refresh_token&' \
'client_id=%s&' \
'client_secret=%s&'\
'refresh_token=%s&' \
'redirect_uri=%s
```

when we try to retrieve new access token for a user, we receive invalid_grant error instead of the fact that no permission is denied to our app from the user's onenote account and it happens **randomly**.

Platform - **python**

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what is happenning without looking at your flow/code. Which platform are you coding in?

I'd encourage you to look at our code samples: https://github.com/onenotedev and find what you are doing differently (or start from the sample and build on it).

Here are a few:
https://github.com/OneNoteDev/OneNoteAPISampleNodejs
https://github.com/OneNoteDev/OneNoteAPISampleWinStore
https://github.com/OneNoteDev/OneNoteAPISamplePHP
https://github.com/OneNoteDev/OneNoteAPISampleAndroid
https://github.com/OneNoteDev/OneNoteAPISampleiOS

Comment: platform used is python